react-native-reanimated-carousel shared value error
[Reanimated] Reading from value during component render. Please ensure that you do not access the value property or use get method of a shared value while React is rendering a component.
This is happening over and over. Is it a problem with the library itself? I don't think I'm doing anything weird in my code:
import Carousel, { ICarouselInstance } from 'react-native-reanimated-carousel';
      <Carousel
        ref={ref as MutableRefObject<ICarouselInstance | null>}
        data={data || []}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.featuredSlide}>
           
            <Image
              style={[styles.featuredImage, { width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight }]} 
              source={{ uri: item.photos?.[0] || 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x480' }}
            />

            {
              showOverlaidText && (
                <>
                  <Text style={styles.a}>{item.a}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.b}>{item.b}</Text>
                </>
              )
            }
          </View>
        )}
        width={width}
        height={height}
        scrollAnimationDuration={scrollAnimationDuration}
        autoPlay={autoPlay}
        loop={loop}
        panGestureHandlerProps={{
          activeOffsetX: [-10, 10],
        }}
      />

I tried the code above. It renders fine. But Im getting thousands of these errors : [Reanimated] Reading from value during component render. Please ensure that you do not access the value property or use get method of a shared value while React is rendering a component.

I resolved this issue by updating the version of the react-native-reanimated-carousel library to the following:
"react-native-reanimated-carousel": "4.0.0-canary.20"

Make sure you are using the latest version of react-native-reanimated and react-native-reanimated-carousel. Sometimes, bugs in earlier versions may cause issues that have been resolved in updates.
also this part of your code can be causing the problem :
<Carousel
  {...}
  panGestureHandlerProps={{
    activeOffsetX: [-10, 10],
  }}
/>

panGestureHandlerProps is used only when thre is a flatlist or scrollview inside your Carousel

Thank you. I did try updating to the latest version. The component is wrapped in a ScrollView. I had to add the panGestureHandlerProps as I was unable to continue to scroll down the page without it when on the carousel
